# Drop Down Menu Title Overlapping with Bar Buttons - Swift

Tags: swift, drop-down-menu, title, uibarbuttonitem, line-breaks

I have [long data modules title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XE5S.png) that overlap with the button on the right. This is a [short data module title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJcNL.png) where the title does not overlap.

For long data modules,I would wan to create a line break to go to the next line and display it there so it would not overlap

**In my code I already set the MaskIntoConstrains to false, what else needs to be done for this functionality to work?**

Code:

```
func createDropDownMenu() {

    // create the drop down menu
    let title = prepareNavigationBarMenuTitleView()
    prepareNavigationBarMenu(title)
    updateMenuContentOffsets()

}

func prepareNavigationBarMenuTitleView() -> String {

    // Both title label and image view are fixed horizontally inside title
    // view, UIKit is responsible to center title view in the navigation bar.
    // We want to ensure the space between title and image remains constant,
    // even when title view is moved to remain centered (but never resized).
    titleView = DropDownTitleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
    titleView.addTarget(self,
                        action: #selector(DocumentViewController.willToggleNavigationBarMenu(_:)),
                        for: .touchUpInside)
    titleView.addTarget(self,
                        action: #selector(DocumentViewController.didToggleNavigationBarMenu(_:)),
                        for: .valueChanged)

    titleView.titleLabel.textAlignment = .left
    titleView.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    titleView.titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleView.title = currentNode.title
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    return titleView.title!
}
```

Comment: Try this code titleView.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the frame of `Titlelabel` , set its frame along with set `numberofLines = 0` will resolve your issue .

Here is the code :

```
titleView.titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 80)
titleView.numberOfLines = 0
//Important one 
titleView.titleLabel.text = currentNode.title
```

This will resolve your issue . Enjoy Coding .